# How to insert empty rows under all (already occupied) rows simultaneously in Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets

How do I insert empty rows under all (already occupied) rows simultaneously in Google Spreadsheets?

Lets say in row 1 it says "A" and in row 2 it says "B", "C" in row 3, etc. I would like it to say "B" in row 3, and "C" in row 5, etc. from now on. Inserting a row underneath one by one is simple. I'm asking about inserting empty rows on a larger scale.

Comment: What do you mean by "simultaneously"? What are you trying to do? What have you already tried that didn't work. As it stands, your question is not very clear.

Comment: Since you cross-posted this on Stack Overflow (something's that's frowned upon) but expanded that post, I've added your changes there to this question here so that it's clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this requires a script, such as this one:

```
function myFunction() {
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
   var range = sheet.getDataRange();
   var values = range.getValues();
   for (var i = values.length; i>=1; i--) {
     if (values[i-1].join("")) {
       sheet.insertRowsAfter(i, 1);
     }
  }
}
```

The command `getDataRange()` selects the range containing data; but since it's possible you have empty rows between filled ones, there is a separate check for nonemptiness of rows: `values[i-1].join("")` evaluates to True only if some data is present. The offset `i-1` is needed because the index in an array is 0-based, while the row numbers begin with 1. I use `i` for row number.

The rows are inserted from bottom up (`i--`), to avoid the situation where newly added rows move down the ones that are still to be processed.

---

To use this:

1. Go to Tools->Script Editor.
2. Copy-paste the script there.
3. Save, renaming to something descriptive like "Extra lines".
4. Click "Run" button.
5. At the first execution (only) you'll be prompted to authorize the script.

[image: script]

Comment: I would just execute from the script page, by pressing "Run" there. I suppose this is not the kind of operation you do many times on the same spreadsheet.

Comment: The function now runs until it exceeds maximum limit, and when I run it again it just applies itself again to the ones that have already been applied. But essentially it does work. Thanks.

Comment: I see: the spreadsheet is so large that the computation times out. When this happens, you can replace "values.length" on line 6 by the number of the last row that was left unprocessed, and run again.

Answer (score 0):

If selecting **some cells** in the spreadsheet:
 1. **Hold** the **ctrl** key down.
 2. **Select** the **cells** that you want to empty.
 3. Once cells are selected, hit the **backspace key**.

If selecting **all cells** in the Spreadsheet:
 1. **Press Ctrl + a**
 2. Once all cells are selected, hit the **backspace key**.

Comment: I know how to erase cells, I'm wondering how to add empty cells in between. Totally different.

Comment: You should have stated this in your original question.

Comment: I did. I wrote "under" not "in".